# after upgrade jquery to 3.0 in meteor getting issue in consloe

Tags: node.js, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have upgrade jquery version to jquery 3.0 in my meteor app. but after upgrade the jquery getting issue in console like
 twbs_bootstrap.js?hash=2ee228e6c80c1d9a4b1e67e10006f8a5a425ddda:42 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

Answer (score 0):

are you using bootstrap in your project?

it looks like there is a confliction...

Comment: Yes, previously I was used jquery 2.2.4, and right now upgrade to jquery 3.0.0, after upgrading its showing error in console. in my project, i'm using twbs:bootstrap@3.3.6